# Changing cursor to custom image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, cursor

I'm trying to write jQuery plugin which replace default cursor to necessary image, but I have a problem with **mouseleave**. It doesn't fire because cursor always before child div and never leave it, so cursor never changes back to default.

## [**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/lafesa/edit?js,output)

Any ideas how to fix it?

By the way: jQuery **mouseleave** behavior is little strange. It fires only when you leave your div and all childe divs.

## [**DEMO 2**](http://jsbin.com/mosose/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

My code:

```
// Plugin changing cursor before element
;
(function ($) {
    $.fn.changeCursor = function (cursorPicUrl, dx, dy) {
        function inFunction(e) {
            $cursor.show();
            return false;
        }
        function outFunction(e) {
            $cursor.hide();
            return false;
        }
        function moveFunction(e) {
            var x = e.clientX-100;
            var y = e.clientY-100;
            $cursor.css({
                "transform": "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)"
            });
        }
        var $cursor = $('<div id="#custom-cursor"></div>').css({
            /*cursor: none;*/
            width:      '150px',
            height:     '150px',
            background: 'url("' + cursorPicUrl + '") no-repeat left top',
            position:   'absolute',
            display:    'none',
            'z-index':  '10000'
        });

        this.append( $cursor )
            .on( "mouseenter", inFunction )
            .on( "mouseleave", outFunction )
            //.hover( inFunction, outFunction)
            .mousemove( moveFunction );
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'http://placehold.it/150x150';
    $('#test-area').changeCursor( url );

});
```

## UPDATE

My solition here:

## **[jquery.change-cursor](https://github.com/Webbrother/jquery.change-cursor)**

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple of adjustments:

1. Store `this` in a variable up front.
2. Attach the cursor div to the body.
3. Add the top/left properties to the cursor.

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/qexawe/edit?js,output)

**Javascript:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.changeCursor = function (cursorPicUrl, dx, dy) {
        var elem = this;
        function inFunction(e) {
            $cursor.show();
            return false;
        }
        function outFunction(e) {
            $cursor.hide();
            return false;
        }
        function moveFunction(e) {
            var x = e.clientX;
            var y = e.clientY;
            $cursor.css({
                "transform": "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)"
            });
        }
        var $cursor = $('<div id="#custom-cursor"></div>').css({
            /*cursor: none;*/
            width:      '150px',
            height:     '150px',
            background: 'url("' + cursorPicUrl + '") no-repeat left top',
            position:   'absolute',
            top: '0',
            left: '0',
            display: 'none'
        });

        $('body').append( $cursor );
        elem.on( "mouseenter", inFunction )
          .on( "mouseleave", outFunction )
          .mousemove( moveFunction );
        return this;
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Thanks.But unfortunately I need crossbrowser solution.

Comment: Yes.  I think your issue is that you're using 'this' to append your cursor div.  I'll update your demo in a moment.

Comment: I updated it, but the performance isn't so good.  It's just a lot of calculations.  Is there any reason why you don't just want to use the css custom cursor?  Check the #test-area2.  You can see that I'm just updating the css of that div with the css cursor property using: cursor: url(cursorimg), auto.  More can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor/url

Comment: The reason why I have to use div with image instead of css custom cursor is size limits of custom cursors. It should be 32x32. But I need bigger cursor.

Comment: Well, then the changes above should work for you.  If you need support for IE8 see my note about using left/top properties instead of transform: translate.  And, if it does work for you please close the question.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking something similar, try this (maybe):

```
$('#selector').css('cursor', 'url("/path/your_image.png"), auto');
```

PS: Doesn't work on primitive browsers!

Comment: I think this is not the OP looking for. As this has size limitation of 32x32. he needed a solution that can add bigger image as cursor